# Optical pulse sensor not producing a clean TTL pulse

Tags: pulse, ttl, light-sensor, optical

I have two of these optical pulse sensors monitoring LEDs on my electric and solar meters - [Optical Pulse Sensor - Github](https://github.com/openenergymonitor/optical-pulse-sensor)

The first sensor outputs nice TTL pulses at 5V, the second sensor outputs pulses at just over 1V and is very noisy and has weird blips in (see scope picture below).

I tested both sensors using a breadboard with various LEDs but they always produced nice looking pulses, so it must be something to do with the way the LED on the solar meter is blinking. I don't understand the circuitry inside the sensor to know what could cause it to output this.

Both sensors are connected to the same Raspberry Pi using the same 5V and GND with each of their pulse/data lines going to a separate GPIO pin.

Any help is much appreciated!

[image]

Comment: We really can't know. Maybe it is not getting its power. Maybe something with the wiring. Maybe too much current is drawn from it. Maybe the sensor is faulty. Test the power on it, then test it standalone, then make sure the GPIO pin is properly configured.

Answer (score 0):

The schematic is incorrect.  For the circuit to produce a positive-going pulse when the optical sensor is illuminated, transistor Q3 must be a PNP (or p-channel) type.  With that change, it looks like it should work as described.

The noise bursts occur at 10 ms intervals, indicating a 50 Hz power system.  They could be coming from anything plugged into the line that has an electronic control - dimmable lights, clothes dryer, induction cooktop, etc.  They might be visible on the output of a properly working unit if the scope scale is expanded enough.

The most likely suspect is the board assembly - solder joints, solder bridges, etc.  Next up is a failed part.  Probe the base of Q1 on the good and bad units and compare.  It should be a sorta kinda square wave moving between 0 V and 0.6 V.